# Can't install isc-dhcp-server on Kali 2.0

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I'm using Kali Linux version 2.0 and I want to install the isc-dhcp-server package in order to practice on an evil twin attack but unfortunately I wasn't able to do that.
I used this command:

```
apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
apt-get install dhcp3-server
```

But I get this error:

[image]

In order to solve this issue I tried a lot of things from here as well as from Google but I got no result.

Some solution that I have tried:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install isc-dhcp-server -y
```

I downloaded the synaptic package manager but I couldn't find the isc-dhcp-server inside it.

[image]

`apt-cache policy isc-dhcp-server` output:

```
isc-dhcp-server:
  Installed: 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6
  Candidate: 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`apt-cache policy isc-dhcp-common` output:

```
isc-dhcp-common:
  Installed: 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6
  Candidate: 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u6 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the output of the following commands? `apt-cache policy isc-dhcp-server` and `apt-cache policy isc-dhcp-common` (and please copy-and-paste the output, it's easier to read than a screen capture).

Comment: @StephenKitt I updated the question with the outputs you've requested.

Comment: Apparently `isc-dhcp-server` is already installed, but it's an old version...

Comment: Can you tell me how can I updated it to the new version??

Comment: Version 4.2.2 should be sufficient to perform an evil twin attack. If you really want to upgrade, you need to check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`; your installation seems messed up somehow, because Kali 2.0 has version 4.3.1 of `isc-dhcp`.

Comment: Because before you send your comment I found a tutorial about how to downgrade the package and I did that that's why the version I have is old.
One more question if you don't mind I was able to create a fake access point but when I try to connect to it with my phone it stuck at "Obtaining IP Address". How can I fix this? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, you should create a new question...

Answer (score 5):

This fixed the problem for me:

```
apt-get purge   isc-dhcp-common  &&
apt-get install isc-dhcp-common  &&
apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the website http://www.isc.org/downloads/ and download the 4.3.4 version.

Then unzip the folder content, on the command line `cd` to the directory and build the dependency tree using `./configure`.

After that type `make` to finish the installation.